# 32-bit VMs stop working after upgrade to Debian 9/Stretch

Tags: debian, vmware, 32bit

Upgraded two 32-bits Debian 8 VMs to Debian 9, in VMWare 5.1.

They stopped working, and going to the console, they are giving errors of wrong CPU architecture.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 9 dropped supported for older 586 based CPUs.

A possible alternative is to install a newer kernel, either with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.7.0-1-686-pae
```

or, as you can boot a 32-bit VM with a 64-bit kernel, with an hypervisor that supports 64-bits:

```
sudo linux-image-4.7.0-1-amd64-unsigned
```

[From the Devel Debian mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2016/05/msg00001.html)

> Last year it was decided to increase the minimum CPU features for the
>   i386 architecture to 686-class in the stretch release cycle.  This
>   means dropping support for 586-class and hybrid 586/686
>   processors[1].(Support for 486-class processors was dropped, somewhat
>   accidentally, in squeeze.)
>
> This was implemented in the Linux kernel packages starting with Linux
>   4.3, which was uploaded to unstable in December last year.
>
> In case you missed that change, gcc for i386 has recently been changed
>   to target 686-class processors and is generating code that will crash
>   on other processors.  Any such systems still running testing or
>   unstable will need to be switched to run stable (jessie).